# Getting an error trying to unwind from a segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

From some reason couple of hours ago the program worked but now I'm getting an error in my unwindToList method:

```
- (IBAction) unwindToList:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{

    NNNAddToDoItemViewController *source = [segue sourceViewController];

    NNNToDoItem *item = source.toDoItem;

    if (item != nil) {
        [self.toDoItems addObject:item];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }

}
```

The app is a to do list app that apple teaches in their "start developing iOS apps today" guid, but after i did it with their guidance I'm trying to do it again without the instructions.

this is an image of the error:

[image]

Comment: That 'error' looks a whole lot like a normal breakpoint (just click that blue square shape on the left near your curly brace to disable it)

Comment: What is the error? you have a breakpoint there (the blue thingy on the left), that's why it's probably stopping. Remove it and try again (right-click, Delete Breakpoint).

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia and matias you guys right, sorry I did not know that :/ thanks